# Partition of $[0, 1]$ contained in a family of open sets.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\{(a_i, b_i)\}$ be a finite collection of open intervals which cover $[0, 1]$. How can we construct a partition $0 = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_n = 1$ such that for all $0 \leq j \leq n - 1$, $[x_j, x_{j + 1}] \subset (a_k, b_k)$ for some $k$?

The argument doesn't necessarily need to be from first principles; I'd be happy to accept something which relies on a more powerful theorem in topology. It's a useful lemma for working with paths, but I've never actually seen a proof of it written down, and I'm not really sure how it would go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Lebesgue Number Lemma. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma

Answer (score 1):

Since $[0,1]$ is sequentially compact, it has a Lebesgue number, say, $\delta>0$, then choose $x_{i}-x_{i-1}<1/N$, $N$ is so large that $1/N<\delta$.